# Difficulty understanding a phrase

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

> At 7:30 a.m. ET on Wednesday, the day after the 2020 presidential elections, the results of the presidential race, as well as control of the Senate, are very much in doubt and in chaos. Watched by rest of the world — deeply affected by who rules the still-imperialist superpower — the U.S. struggles and stumbles and staggers to engage in a simple task mastered by countless other less powerful and poorer countries: counting votes.
>
> [Glenn Greenwald](https://greenwald.substack.com/p/the-us-inability-to-count-votes-is) on Substack

I find this quote online and is having a hard time digesting what seems to be an awkward sentence, "deeply affected by who rules the still imperialist superpower". Is the world the subject? The world is deeply affected?

USA is the object? USA is the one who rules the still imperialist superpower? What does that even mean?

Comment: This is a tedious bit of writing. The parenthetical part _deeply affected by who rules the still-imperialist superpower_ refers to *the world* here. *USA* would be the subject of the sentence. *who rules the still-imperialist superpower* means the person who is going to be the next POTUS.

Comment: I agree with @Pkjmm that the world is most probably referred to, but nevertheless recognise that the sentence is ambiguous in the sense that you have described.

Answer (score 0):

"deeply affected ..." modifies "the rest of the world" -- ie, the rest of the world is deeply affected. "still-imperialist superpower" is presumably referring to the US.

And note that "deeply affected ... superpower" is a "parenthetical" and can be omitted when analyzing the syntax of the sentence.

(And I agree with Pkjmm that the writing is tedious at best.)